# Can not load resource from package

Tags: java, java-module, java-11, java-platform-module-system

I have a problem which seems to be very basic and simple but I am not able to solve it, even though I made investigations on the Internet. Since I believe that I ran into a corner and being not able to find my way out, I will state my very simple question here.

Given: A JDK 11 project containing one module called `LoadResource`.

*Project structure*

```
src
└── main
    ├── java
    │   ├── module-info.java
    │   └── com
    │       └── example
    │           └── LoadResource.java
    └── resources
        └── com
            └── example
                └── Foo.txt
```

*module-info.java*

```
module {
  exports example.com;
}
```

*LoadResource.java*

```
package com.example;

public class LoadResource {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new LoadResource().run();
    }

    private void run() {
        System.out.println("TEST");

        final var resource = getClass().getResource("Foo.txt");
        System.out.println(resource);
    }
}
```

If I run this `getClass().getResource("Foo.text");` returns `null`.

I know that's a very basic question, but: Why is that? To me, that looks like a rather simple programming task. What do I miss here?

Comment: /com/example/Foo.txt. the resources folder is the root in the classpath

Comment: @HenningLuther This does not work either.

Comment: is your resources folder in classpath? ide?

Comment: Can you show us the output directory? If Foo.txt is in the same directory as LoadResource.class then it will be found, ditto when you create the JAR file as they will be in the same "directory". Otherwise it looks like an IDE or environment issue where Foo.txt is not copied to the right location.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my problem by adding `--patch-module LoadResource=build/resources/main` as VM args in IntelliJ.

Comment: how about `final var resource = getClass().getResource("com/example/Foo.txt");`?

Comment: If this --patch-module option is working then it suggests that resources have been copied into build/resources/main so they are not in the same tree as the class files - this should be reported to whatever IDE you are using as it must be coping them to the wrong location.